# openpyxlで行順に処理していくが特定行だけを編集したい

Tags: python, python3, excel, openpyxl

openpyxlで行ごとにA,D,F列の値を読み取り、編集してエクセルに入力し直すようなプログラムを作成したいのですが、調べてみると

```
sheet.cell(row=1,column=2).value = 100
```

のようにセルを行列指定して記入するような方法しかわかりませんでした。
私は行ごとに処理を行いたいのですが、何かいい書き方はありますでしょうか。

お詳しい方、よろしくお願いいたします。
（できれば1行目の読み込み→編集→2行目の読み込み→編集→…のような感じにしたいです。）

Comment: タイトルの特定「行」は特定「列」の間違いでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

行ごとの指定は次のようにできます

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='file_name.xlsx')
ws = wb['test_data']

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)

wb.close()
```

手もとに Windows無いので試せないけど, たぶん範囲指定もできたはず (未確認)

```py
for row in ws['A3:F10']:
    for c in row:
        border = copy(c.border)
        c.value = '置き換える内容'
        c.border = border

    print(row[1].value +row[2].value)
```

---

##### 追記

その他に pandasで読み取り加工する方法も

```py
df = pd.read_excel('data/src/sample.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

Comment: お教え頂いた方法でできました！ありがとうございます。
pandas使った方が簡単そうですね！そっちも少し勉強してみます。

Comment: 補足必要な気もするのでコメントで。`row` は 1行分のデータ。`c` はカラム。'A','D','F' ならば, `row[0]`, `row[3]`, `row[5]`

Comment: なるほど！！理解しました。そういう感じで行からセルを選択できるんですね。